# Proper pressure for run-flats on Mini Cooper

Tags: tires, service, mini-cooper

I have custom rims and Kumho 205/45/RF17 [run-flats](http://www.carid.com/kumho-tires/ecsta-spt-run-flat-205-45r17-469606.html) on my 2007 R56 Mini Cooper S (not convertible), and the tire pressure light came on. I checked, and indeed one of the tires was low (around 29 psi) but when I inflated them all to 38, in the service menu, the warning still did not give me an option to dismiss.

Now I can't find the correct psi for these tires. The Max Pressure on the side says 51 (!) but the recommendation on the sticker on the inside of the door was 38. Does the sticker apply no matter what rims and tires I have on there?

EDIT: I still am wondering if the sticker on the door applies to ALL tires you could put on a car. However I found a step-by-step [guide to resetting the pressure alert](https://wiki.bentleypublishers.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=68452354), which I will also try.

Comment: The procedure varies by model year. Can you post some specifics, Mini model year and tire brand and model.

Comment: Thanks @mikes. I edited the question to include more specifics.

Comment: @beroe: first make sure these are NOT sensors that can only be cleared by the dealership. Lexus does this on some vehicles.

Comment: That is a good point, Greg. It is possible, but I have gotten the tires (and rims) replaced by third-party shops before, and they were able to reset. I think the pressure sensor is actually a balance sensor of some kind, right? In the manual it shows a "Reset Alert" function but it doesn't show up in my console next to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out (oops) a detailed answer is in the owner's manual: For the Cooper S and my size, it looks like 36 psi. (Ignore the asterisk -- that was for my old tires.)

[image: Tire pressure]

Answer (score 1):

For my R56 diesel Mini Cooper D (aka "Dooper") running 205/45/R/17 tyres, the reading given on the door pillar is 2.2 bar (32psi).